# Changing my footer which is PHP, having trouble (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked around for instructions on changing the copyright found within the footer, currently set at:

> © 2014 Toronto Booze Hound. Theme by XtremelySocial and Blacktie.

I have found instructions in the past to change this, but changes made to this code:

```
add_filter('xsbf_credits', 'xsbf_child_credits');
function xsbf_child_credits ( $site_credits ) {

    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $site_credits = sprintf( __( '&copy; 2014 - %1$s %2$s'),
        date ( 'Y' ),
        '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" rel="home">' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .     '</a>'
    );
    return $site_credits;
}
```

Don't seem to reflect on the page.

Here are the notes by the author in the code:

```
    /*
 * OVERRIDE THE SITE CREDITS TO GET RID OF THE "THEME BY XTREMELYSOCIAL" AND JUST LEAVE
 * COPYRIGHT YOUR SITE NAME
 * 
 * You can hard-code whatever you want in here, but its better to have this function pull
 * the current year and site name and URL as shown below.
 */
```

It's possible I'm not fully understanding the php. The end-goal is to have it changed to a simple:

> 2014 - ($currentDate) Toronto Booze Hound

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Site is https://torontoboozehound.com

I do understand that having both wpsupercache and cloudflare on would make changes take some time, but I clear the cache within the plugin and put cloudflare into developer mode as well as use incognito mode to look for changes.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only loosely related to programming and would be better placed on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**The easy way**

Go to your footer.php file and delete:

```
Theme by %3$s. (line 63)
'<a href="' . $theme->get( 'ThemeURI' ) . '" rel="profile" target="_blank">' . $theme->get( 'Author' ) . '</a>' (line 66)
```

should end this way:

```
$site_credits = sprintf( __( '&copy; %1$s %2$s.', 'flat-bootstrap' ), 
        date ( 'Y' ),
        '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" rel="home">' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '</a>',
    );
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked! Sorry, I didn't see your response for a bit.